# downloading an image using https.get in node produces a corrupt image when using in pdflatex

Tags: node.js, download, pdflatex

I have set up a node server that handles requests to convert latex to a rendered pdf using PDFLateX. If the document requires extra assets, e.g. images I download them first and then start the pdflatex process. If the images are downloaded using the http.get client and saved using fs.createWriteStream they appear correctly in the final file.

This Url for example works fine: [image over https](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Sunflower_from_Silesia2.jpg/1200px-Sunflower_from_Silesia2.jpg)

Now if I serve the same image but over http: [image over http](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Sunflower_from_Silesia2.jpg/1200px-Sunflower_from_Silesia2.jpg) it corrupts the file that is included in the final pdf. The Image would be greatly distorted, but displayed. The File that is written to the filesystem is correct and is not corrupted however.

The code that downloads the file looks like this:

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs-promise');

    /**
     * Downloads a single Asset
     *
     * @param url Url to an Image
     * @param dest Path where it will be saved
     * @returns {Promise}
     */
    function download (url, dest) {
        console.log('Downloading Asset from: ' + url + ' to ' + dest);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);

            let link = new URL(url);
            let client = (link.protocol.includes('https')) ? https : http;

            client.get(url, function(response) {
                response.pipe(file);
                file.on('close', function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        resolve();
                    },10)
                });
            }).on('error', function(err) {
                fs.unlink(dest);
                reject();
            });
        });
    }
```

As you can see I even tried a timeout to delay the resolve event, just in case 'close' gets fired a bit early. But this does not help.
I start the PdfLateX process after all Download Processes are done, e.g. after the function below resolves.

```
/**
 * Downloads all needed Assets to /assets/
 *
 * @param assetUrls Array of Objects that contain urls and names
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function downloadAssets(assetUrls){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let requests = [];
        if(assetUrls){
            assetUrls = JSON.parse(assetUrls);
            for(let asset of assetUrls){
                requests.push(download(asset.url, './assets/' + asset.name));
            }
        }
        Promise.all(requests)
          .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
              reject('Download of one or more assets failed!');
          })
          .then(() => {
              resolve();
          });
    })
}
```

This is running with Node 12.16.2 inside a Docker Container.

I tried several methods of downloading the Images, but every time the Image is served over https it ends up corrupted in the final Pdf, but intact when looking at id directly in the file system.

One more thing to note is, that the image always corrupts in the same way. There is no variation, a specific image served over https will always break in the same way.

Any clue what could cause this would be greatly appreciated, as I could not find any solutions when searching the web.

Comment: For future readers: I found that the issue does not lie in the generation of the pdf itself, the final file is correct. The Image gets corrupted when answering the initial request with the final file. I still have no idea why this happens and/or why this only happens when the image is served by https but I am a step closer to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This has sorted itself out. The problem did not lie in the creation of the document, but rather how i passed the data on between services. On one point I had a filter in place where raw text data whould be parsed for php variables starting with $. By mistake the raw pdf data went through this filter and thus got corrupted. I assume only images downloaded via https contain $ signs in the raw data string, thus the corruption only appears when using https.